# Prestashop - Integrate Bizum method

Tags: php, prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to integrate the BIZUM payment method in a prestashop store and for this I have installed the payment method addon "redsys" and I am modifying it, for what I have done is take the file redsys.php from the module and modify it by this code

```
        /*
 * HOOK V1.7
 */
public function hookPaymentOptions($params) {

if (! $this->active) {
    return;
}

if (! $this->checkCurrency ( $params ['cart'] )) {
    return;
}

$this->createParameter($params);


$urlBizum = 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago';

    $newOption2 = new \PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Payment\PaymentOption();
    $newOption2->setCallToActionText ($this->l('Pago con Bizum' ))
        ->setAction ($urlBizum)
        ->setInputs([
            'Ds_SignatureVersion' => [
                'name' =>'Ds_SignatureVersion',
                'type' =>'hidden',
                'value' =>$this->version2,
            ],
            'Ds_MerchantParameters' => [
                'name' =>'Ds_MerchantParameters',
                'type' =>'hidden',
                'value' =>$this->paramsBase64,
            ],
            'Ds_Signature' => [
                'name' =>'Ds_Signature',
                'type' =>'hidden',
                'value' => $this->signatureMac,
            ],
            'Ds_Merchant_PayMethods' => [
                'name' =>'Ds_Merchant_PayMethods',
                'type' =>'hidden',
                'value' => 'z',
            ],
        ]);

    $payment_options = [$newOption2];

    return $payment_options;
}
```

The problem I have is that I get the redsys TVP screen ... and not the bizum I'm waiting for.

Thank you

Comment: The URL is https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago...

Comment: @Anfuca thanxs for your time